# Error in running printed variables with Visual Studio using Python

Tags: python, undefined

I am doing the Code with Mosh Python program. Every time I try to run code in Visual Studio it gives me an error:

```
course = 'python programming'
print(len(course))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'course' is not defined
```

I googled the error and wasn't getting relevant solutions. I think that I have set something up wrong with Visual Studio.

I want to get this fixed so that I can take the class with running code. Also I like Visual Studio more than Jupyter Notebooks which I had been using previously.

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and it is running correctly for me. Make sure your Visual Studio has Python Extension for VS code. I hope this helps.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: It looks like there are many extensions:
*IntelliCode
*IntelliCode API Usage Examples
*Emojy
*Python
*Git Base
*autoDocstring - Python Docstring Generator
*Jupyter
*Microsoft Account
*Django
*Code Runner
*Pylance
*Python Indent
*WSL Recommender
*Github
*Git
*Merge Conflict
*Emmet
*Github Authentication
*isort
*Node Debug Auto-attach
*Jupyter Notebook Renderers